# How to transform xml file to another file using xslt ? The code should be in java

Tags: xml, xslt

I am getting fatal error:
The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.

ERROR:  'The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:stylesheet" is not bound.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(Unknown Source)
    at com.quicklyjava.JavaXSLT.main(JavaXSLT.java:20)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"> 
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <body>
    <h1>Movies</h1>
    <table border="3">
     <tr bgcolor="grey">
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Director</th>
    <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
     <tr>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@genre"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="director"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
   </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're missing the `xsl` namespace declaration:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

Comment: @user3073182 To be more clear, please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Also, I know we all have to start somewhere, but I'm puzzled as to why it was necessary to ask this question. If the message isn't self-explanatory, then you need to do some reading before do any more coding; you're not going to understand error messages unless you understand the concepts of the language, and the only way to understand the concepts is to read before your write.